# Simple SQLiteDatabase usage in android

Tags: android

My purpose is to show the last KEY_CASH value in the TABLE_CB on the MainActivity

The MainActivity part work fine if it is not related to getCash() method.

Could you please tell me what are the problems in the getCash() method?

This is my first time using SQLite, so it is difficult to find the answer.

```
//TABLE_CB has two columns (long)KEY_ID and (integer)KEY_CASH
//CashBalanceTable class is just an description of a database to move data
package com.example.money;

public class CashBalanceTable {

    private int id;
    private int cash;

    public CashBalanceTable() {}
    public CashBalanceTable(int id, int cash)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.cash = cash;
    }
    public CashBalanceTable(int cash)
    {
        this.cash = cash;
    }

    public void setCash(int cash)
    {
        this.cash = cash;
    }

    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public int getCash()
    {
        return cash;
    }
}



//Main Activity
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    TextView textView1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);        
        DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        CashBalanceTable cb = new CashBalanceTable();
        cb = dbHelper.getCash();
        textView1.setText("Cash : " + cb.getCash() + " won");
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////     

//In DatabaseHelper getCash() method
public CashBalanceTable getCash()
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_CASH };
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CB, columns, "cash=?", null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToLast();
        int cash = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CASH));
        CashBalanceTable cb = new CashBalanceTable(cash);
        return cb;

    }
```

//DatabaseHelper
    public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
    //database version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    //database name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "APP_DATABASE";

    //table names
    private static final String TABLE_CB = "cashBalanceTable";

    //common column names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_CASH = "cash";

   //cashBalanceTable creation statement
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_CB = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CB + " (" + KEY_ID + "           I       INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_CASH + " INTEGER );";
    //ingore the I on the left;;

    private Context context;

    //constructor
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {
        try {
            // creating required tables
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_CE);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_CA);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_AE);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_AA);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_CB);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_AI);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Message.message(context, ""+e);
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
        try {
            //on upgrade drop older tables
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CE);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CA);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_AE);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_AA);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CB);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_AI);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Message.message(context, ""+e);
        }
        //create new tables
        onCreate(db);
    }

    //Insert initial cash value to cashBalanceTable (input class)
    public long insertCash(CashBalanceTable cb)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_CASH, cb.getCash());

        //insert a row
        long id = db.insert(TABLE_CB, null, values);    
        return id;
    }


    public CashBalanceTable getCash()
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_CASH };
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CB, columns, "cash=?", null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToLast();
        int cash = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CASH));
        CashBalanceTable cb = new CashBalanceTable(cash);
        return cb;

    }

}
```

Comment: have you tried `return this.cash;` ?

Comment: I just tried it in the getCash() method in CashBalanceTable class but it didn't work;;

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work"? Do you get any exception?

Comment: Why did you type `cursor.moveToLast()`? Type `if(cursor.moveToFirst())` to see if your cursor is returning anything

Comment: what is the meaning of the "cash=?"

Comment: There is no typical problem. However, in the emulator,             it says that the app is stoped. It cannot be opened;;

Comment: Replacing "cash=?" to null solves the problem.. Thank you for all of you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think, you haven't pass selectionArgs in the method, please revise your code.

```
public CashBalanceTable getCash()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_CASH };
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CB, columns, "cash=?", new String[]{selectionArgs }, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToLast();
    int cash = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CASH));
    CashBalanceTable cb = new CashBalanceTable(cash);
    return cb;

}
```